# Is it possible to remove the dash window control buttons?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, window-buttons

Is it possible to change or remove the Unity dash window control buttons (Close, Minimize, Maximize) in Ubuntu 11.10? I'm not a huge fan of how they look and would like to swap them out if possible.

Answer (score 1):

There is no current way to change the order of those buttons nor is there a plan to add that option.

Comment: I don't want to reorder the buttons, I simply meant the icons themselves. They don't seem to match any theme and I think they make the dash look unprofessional, like the window controls were an afterthought. I think the dash would look better with the icons from the user's window theme or even not there at all, similar to 11.04's dash. I must be in the minority though, because I haven't seen anyone else bring it up.

Answer (score 1):

**For those who would like to see the window control buttons of a theme in Ubuntu 12.10 Unity Dash window:**

1) You can use this script http://ubuntuone.com/0aCYqRY1ZWRbxlUj3a0Kqe to **backup** the default ones, and

2) You can use this script http://ubuntuone.com/3O1sLMJftDALGpHjtnWjG3 to create symbolic links to relevant images in the **unity** sub-folder of the theme, or

3) You can use this script http://ubuntuone.com/25S7Zqw4eSeR0RjP4Xk5tT to create symbolic links to relevant images in the **metacity** sub-folder of the theme, if it doesn't have a unity sub-folder, and

4) You can use this script http://ubuntuone.com/37Mj4kbBh90LNNunEi4Cxs to **create unity sub-folder** if there isn't one and create symbolic links to relevant images in the metacity sub-folder of the theme as this will display the same control buttons in the unity panel as well.

**Note:** These scripts assume that the current theme is under the system folder "/usr/share/themes" and should be modified otherwise.
The first can be run by user from anywhere, the second one should be placed into the "unity" and third one should be placed into the "metacity-1" sub-folder of the theme and the fourth one should be placed into the theme folder, and each should be run from its own location in the terminal window.