# How can I remove Unity's Max/Min/Close buttons on the top left of the Dash?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to remove the dash window control buttons?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66920/is-it-possible-to-remove-the-dash-window-control-buttons)

How can I remove Unity's Max/Min/Close buttons on the top left of the Dash?

Personally, I feel that they look out of place and since I never use them, I'd like to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu Tweak application can do that for you. You'll find it at:

http://ubuntu-tweak.com

You find what you want in the Tweaks tab under "Window Manager Settings". Within "Window Titlbar Button Layout" check the Customize box and then uncheck the boxes in "Enable control:".